# Not able to grep pattern between a date range

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I am  trying to fetch lines which are within a specified date range. I have tried many online solutions they did not work

Below is the log file I have

```
Nov 21 03:31:28 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:32:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:33:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:34:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:35:02 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:36:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:37:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:38:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:39:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:39:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:39:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:40:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:40:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:40:29 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:40:29 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:41:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:41:22 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:41:22 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:41:43 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:41:43 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:42:01 Sample Log test
```

Awk command I am using is

```
-bash-4.2$ b="03:31:28"
-bash-4.2$ e="03:41:00"
-bash-4.2$ awk -v "b=$b" -v "e=$e" -F ',' '$1 >= b && $1 <= e' ~/test
-bash-4.2$
```

It is not returning output

Comment: Are there log entries only for a single day as shown in sample data?

Comment: Why do you use a comma as your field separator (`-F ','`) while there are no commas in your file? And why do you compare field number 1 (`$1`) while your time field is the third?

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk -v b=03:31:28 -v e=03:41:00 '$3 >= b && $3 <= e' input_file
Nov 21 03:31:28 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:32:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:33:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:34:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:35:02 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:36:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:37:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:38:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:39:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:39:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:39:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:40:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:40:01 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:40:29 Sample Log test
Nov 21 03:40:29 Sample Log test
```